# Displaying JPA resultList in console

Tags: database, hibernate, jpa, console, display

I've just started to learn JPA 2 and am trying to make a simple display of my table content in console.

This is how my method looks like:

```
public static List<Bronie> getListaBroni() {

    EntityManager em = DatabaseHandler.getEntityManager();
    String qString = "SELECT b FROM Bronie b";

    TypedQuery<Bronie> q = em.createQuery(qString, Bronie.class);

    result = q.getResultList();

    return result;

}
```

I'm trying to display it in console, but the result I get is:

```
Hibernate: select bronie0_.id as id1_1_, bronie0_.ilosc as ilosc2_1_, bronie0_.kaliber as kaliber3_1_, bronie0_.model_broni as model_br4_1_ from bronie bronie0_
[arma.itemdb.Bronie@7662c85f]
```

So far there's only one object in the database, but I see no point of putting more of them for this question.

I know I have to, somehow, divide the objects I receive in parts that represent different columns, but I have no clue how. And how to avoid this kind of display

```
Bronie@7662c85f
```

later?

Don't know if it helps, but I'll be trying to put the result list into a TableView at the end, so I'll probably need to separate each column from the object anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you try to print a object it calls the `toString()` method on it. The default implementation returns the object class and hashcode. So if you want to print the Bronie object data you have to `@Override` the `toString()` method in you class.

```
@Override
public String toString() { 
    return "Prop1: '" + this.prop1+ "', Prop2: '" + this.prop2+ "'....;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your class should implement **Serializable** class.

Answer (score 0):

I see three parts in your question:

In the first part of your question you are displaying the SQL query that hibernate creates to query the database to recover the rows. The dynamic table and column names are strange but it's an implementation detail.

In the second part of your question you talks about a neeed to separate columns. You don't have to separate anything, your query goes like this:

- The entity manager reads the database row
- Instantiates and object of the class mapped and requested
- Initializes the properties of the object with data in the row

Third part, printing an object:

The print result you showed is the default, the class name with the address in the Virtual Machine. As others say, you can Override the toString method to change default behaviour, and print by default wathever you like. Please consider default printing something internal and create custom methos for end user views or printing.